# Digest authentication with Jetty Websocket client

Tags: java, authentication, jetty, client

I want to write a Java Websocket client which needs digest authentication to authenticate at a server.

I played around with the [Jetty Websocket client example](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/jetty-websocket-client-api.html) but I have no idea how to easily add the digest authentication. Furthermore I found no online resources which give a hint on how it could be done.

I also find it quite hard to find information online as most people use Jetty as server (obviously). For example this is not a duplicate: [How to authenticate websocket client in jetty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897990/how-to-authenticate-websocket-client-in-jetty)

Therefore I am wondering if it is possible to use digest authentication with the Jetty Websocket client?

Answer (score 2):

you can try these two method:

1. put your username and password in the websocket url.
   eg. ws://username:password@www.example.com/resturl
2. generate Authorization and put this to the request header.

   ```
   String userpass = accessKey + ":" + secretKey;

   String authorization = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes())).trim();

   ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();

   request.setHeader("Authorization", authorization);
   ```